# Disposing a JFrame in catch block if initialised in try block

Tags: java, swing, jframe, try-catch

```
private void by_bill_no(int bill_no) {
        this.dispose();
        Purchase pur=null;
        try {
            pur = new Purchase(bill_no);
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            n.printStackTrace();
            pur.dispose();
            new ViewPurchase();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("message"), "Bill no : " + bill_no + " not found");
        }
    }
```

In the above code I have created an instance 'pur' of class Purchase which is extended to JFrame.
When I passes a bill number that does not exist it passes NullPointerException but it creates a frame window how to dispose that window.(I dont want to make changes in Purchase class) I want to ask is there any way to dispose it here.

*ViewPurchase is this class... which will be recreated if bill number is wrong so that user can try with another input*

Comment: sleepToken sir I am trying creating UI in that class. I learned it from a youtube video

Comment: @sleepToken I am having database linked in Purchase class which is not connected in this class... I willl have to connect and check if I do it thatway

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't add further information in comments. Instead [edit] the question. 3) I can see no way that code could produce a `NullPointerException` - a MRE should make it clear.